# Realm Kotlin migration Android String

Tags: android, kotlin, migration, realm

Can't find an answer.
I'm trying to migrate Realm database. Need to create a table DBRequest with 2 fields: Int and String

```
if (oldVersion == 5L) {
    val s = scheme.create("DBRequest")
    s.addField("apiCode", Int::class.java)
}
```

And that's ok! But if I'm trying to add String type as well

```
    s.addField("jsonRequest", String::class.java)
```

it throws an error:

> Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:
>       - Property 'DBRequest.jsonRequest' has been made required.

I have no idea how to sort it out. I've tried smth like this:

```
s.addField("jsonRequest", String::class.javaPrimitiveType!!)
-or-
s.addField("jsonRequest", String::class.javaObjectType)
```

Nothing helps :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to the migration

```
s
    .addField("jsonRequest", String::class.java)
    .setRequired("jsonRequest", true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option for the non-primitive type of String:

```
s.addField("jsonRequest", String::class.java, FieldAttribute.REQUIRED)
```

For required `Int` though, you'd normally use `int.class` or `Integer.class`, which is why you use `javaPrimitiveType` or `javaObjectType` accordingly.